# Change text inside a button on each click using javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I need to change text each time I click on button.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("changeText");
button.addEventListener(
"click",
function () {
    if (button.getAttribute("data-text") == button.innerHTML) {
        button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text1");
    } else {
        button.setAttribute("data-text1", button.innerHTML);
        button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("data-text");
    }
},
false
);
```

```html
<div>
<button id="changeText" data-text="Show" data-text1="Hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

I don't understand why this code doesn't work when I try to load page using google chrome. However when I loaded it to codepen it worked

Comment: You shouldn't make up your own attributes. If you need custom data, use `data-XXX` attributes.

Comment: It works in the snippet here.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you run it on your real web page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It expects from you certain structure like this one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
              
        </title>
    </head>
      
    <body>
        <div>
            <button id="changeText" text="Show" >Hide</button>
        </div>

        <script>
            var button = document.getElementById("changeText");
button.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function () {
        if (button.getAttribute("text") == button.innerHTML) {
            button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("text1");
        } else {
            button.setAttribute("text1", button.innerHTML);
            button.innerHTML = button.getAttribute("text");
        }
    },
    false
);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Copy paste it to your file and you'll see that it works.
Please mark it as an answer if it fixes your problem :)

Comment: it works, but i have two separate files .HTML and .js and it doesn't work that way

Comment: Try to check correctness of your js path. Are there any other errors?

Comment: no other errors, the path is <script defer src="part2.js"></script>

Comment: Make sure that your script is located inside body tag, also check if your .js script is in the same folder where your .html file is. I have just separated that piece of code that I posted to 2 different files (.js and .html) in the same folder and it still works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, but your approach is not so nice. See the 2 options down below.

```js
let text = {
 'Hide': 'Show',
 'Show': 'Hide'
}

const click = (event) => {
  // option 1, it needs the object above.
  // It's good for multiple alternatiosn like color, icon etc
  // or multiple states like hide to show, show to sure, sure to really, really to hide. 
  event.target.innerText = text[event.target.innerText];
  
  // option 2, it's good for one or two alternations.
  // event.target.innerText = event.target.innerText == 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide'
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', click);
```

```html
<button>Show</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make it more simple by removing the custom attribute and use the button innerHTML only along with enum by using Object.freeze(),it will make the code more readable

```js
const titleEnum = Object.freeze({show: "SHOW",  hide: "HIDE"});
var button = document.getElementById("changeText");
button.addEventListener(
    "click",
    function () {
        if (button.innerHTML === titleEnum.hide) {
            button.innerHTML = titleEnum.show;
        } else {
            button.innerHTML = titleEnum.hide;
        }
    },
    false
);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
              
        </title>
    </head>
      
    <body>
        <div>
            <button id="changeText">HIDE</button>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **innerText** to get the value of an element

```js
const changeBtn = document.getElementById("changeText");
changeBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    if(changeBtn.innerText === "2"){
        changeBtn.innerText = "1";
    }
    else{
        changeBtn.innerText= "2";
    }
});
```

```html
<div>
    <button id="changeText">1</button>
</div>
```